# OnClick event table won't trigger properly

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This code is designed to show and hide a table based on a button click, however, it doesn't seem to toggle it properly. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <br>
        <button onclick="toggleTable();" style="position:absolute; top:130px; left:1000; width:200px; height:25px">3-D Model</button>

    <br>
</body>

<script>

    function toggleTable()
{

var status = document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display;

if (status == 'block') {
  document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display="none";
} else {
  document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display="block";
}
}

    <table id="modelTable" border="1" align="right" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:150px; left:1000;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="google.com"> 3-D Model </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a>test1</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a>test2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</script>
```

Comment: your marksup is invalid, you need to place the tabel within body

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your marksup is invalid, you need to place the tabel within body

```
<body>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="toggleTable();" style="position:absolute; top:130px; left:1000; width:200px; height:25px">3-D Model</button>
    <br/>
    <table id="modelTable" border="1" align="right" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:150px; left:1000;">
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="google.com"> 3-D Model </a>

            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a>test1</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a>test2</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        function toggleTable() {
            var table = document.getElementById("modelTable");
            var status = table.style.display;
            if (status == 'block') {
                table.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                table.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f4vgS/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code :
    var status = document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display;
    if (status == 'block') {
      document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display="none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("modelTable").style.display="block";
    }

IT might be better to use css:

The css : 
    .hide { display: none; }

The javascript: 
    document.getElementById('modelTable').classList.toggle('hide');